# How to exclude in file all rows which contains date or brackets

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

How to exclude in file all rows which contains date and bracket

In my case:

```
2015-01-16 12:51:34,787 | [D] | query.Selao | ref:5463| 13 | Selao .select | Binding 4 to 432| [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.api.base.dataaccess.elen(elen.java:424)
2015-01-16 12:51:34,788 | [D] | query.Selao | ref:5464| 14 | Selao .select | Binding 5 to 433| [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'
   <list>
    <Filters class="com.base.Filter">
     <Negated value="false"/>
    </Filters>
   </list>
```

Expected after exclude:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.api.base.dataaccess.elen(elen.java:424)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
egrep -v '([0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2})|(\[.*\])' YourFile
```

but what about `<LIST>` in your post ? there is no date nor bracket but not in expected output ?

if bracket are not `[]` but `<>`

```
egrep -v '([0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2})|(<.*>)' YourFile
```

for all the 3

```
egrep -v '([0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2})|(<.*>)|(\[.*\])' YourFile
```

Comment: This is some configuration values which I want to exclude also

Comment: i adapt the post for the 3 exclusions than

Comment: Third version works perfect because in first two cases i get output like that:
` | [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'`

Answer (score 1):

Use awk,

```
$ awk '!/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|<.*>/' file
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.api.base.dataaccess.elen(elen.java:424)
```

OR

```
grep -v '[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\|<.*>' file
```

Comment: Is there are any why to exclude also the brackets I update the query?

Answer (score 1):

How about a `sed` solution to delete all lines that contain specific patterns:

```
sed '/20[0-9][0-9]-[0-9]/d;/\<.*\>/d' file
```